# Black spots on my Roblox rig (Roblox Starter Pack Rigs)

Tags: materials

Okay, so I downloaded the Roblox starter rigs pack and when I select a rig it appears with some black things in the material preview and render view. In Cycles I don’t see the black things but in EEVE I do. I tried to load it on the 3.5 and 4.0 and it stills the same. Im using a Mac. Thanks!
[image: This is a screenshot of the problem.]